# Probability of going from a set $S$ to its complement on a Markov chain

Tags: probability-theory, markov-chains, markov-process

I need to show that if $\pi$ is the stationary distribution of a Markov chain $M$, then for every set of vertices $S$, the probability to choose a random node in $S$ according to $\pi$ and then going to a random neighbor not in $S$ $\left(\sum_{u\in S,v\notin S}\pi(u)M(u,v)\right)$ equals to the probability of choosing a random vertex not in S according to $\pi$ and going to a random neighbor in $S$ $\left(\sum_{u\in S,v\notin S}\pi(v)M(v,u)\right)$

Intuitively I can see why its true, but when I tired to prove it using the identity $\pi = M\pi$ I didn't manage to get anywhere :(

Any ideas people?

Comment: "Intuitively I can see why its true" Please describe your intuition.

Comment: "Compliment" with an "i" means saying this question is brilliant; the "complement" (with an "e") of something is what you need to add to it to make it complete.  Just remember the resemblance in spelling between "complement" and "complete".  (I changed it.) ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: To be honest I don't understand the question. Consider a two state Markov Chain and let $S=\{1\}$ and let $ S^c=\{2\}$. The probability that after randomly choosing an element in $S$ then getting into $S^c$ means (to me) that we assume that $X_n=1$. Then (as far as I can see) the probability, we are looking for, is $P(X_{n+1}\notin S|X\in S)=p_{12}$. Why would $p_{12}$ equal $p_{21}$, the other probability?